# Application to get system login events in Android

Tags: windows-7, android

Is there any application to get a notification in my android phone when someone logs into my windows laptop?

Both my devices are internet connected.

Comment: Please write what you have tried or looked for so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Windows Task Scheduler to [get email notifications when someone logs into your computer](http://lifehacker.com/5941294/use-windows-task-scheduler-to-get-email-notifications-when-someone-logs-into-your-computer).